# Display the alternate UIKeyboardType

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyboardtype

I would like to immediately display the alternate view 2 of the default`UIKeyboardType` (instead of requiring the user to tap **123**); it is the one that shows punctuation marks.  Is there any way to code this?

Comment: i have posted the answer please check it and inform me.

Comment: can you up vote for my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set Property from Interface builder. See the Image and select **Number and punctuation** option.

**Image:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If it is a `UITextField` there is an option to specify the **Keyboard Type** as **Numbers and Punctuation** type in the storyboard itself!

Cheers :)